# Loggly doesn't parse Heroku logs format

Tags: heroku, loggly

I'm running a [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) app on Heroku. I've connected the logs output to Loggly, however trying Loggly's verify step, I receive the following message:

> We received your logs but they do not appear to use one of our
>   automated parsing formats. Please see our guide to learn more (link).
>   You can still do full text search and counts on these logs, but you
>   won't be able to use some features like filtering by field.

**Why doesn't Loggly parse Heroku's logs well? What can I change so it will?**
The logs appear to be quite standard for Heroku, here's an example:

```
2014-08-26 11:06:00 [2] [INFO] 1 workers
2014-08-26 11:05:45 [2] [INFO] 1 workers
2014-08-26 11:05:16 [2] [INFO] 1 workers
at=info method=GET path="/" host=my-app.herokuapp.com request_id=925f3605-2ac4-4182-b148-987ab7d985c4 fwd="91.271.61.73" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=200 bytes=608
Process exited with status 0
2014-08-26 11:04:47 [2] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2014-08-26 11:04:47 [2] [INFO] 1 workers
2014-08-26 11:04:47 [2] [INFO] Handling signal: term
2014-08-26 11:04:47 [7] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 7)
State changed from starting to up
2014-08-26 11:04:46 [2] [INFO] 1 workers
2014-08-26 11:04:46 [7] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7
2014-08-26 11:04:46 [2] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:26268 (2)
2014-08-26 11:04:46 [2] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2014-08-26 11:04:46 [2] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.1.0
Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
Starting process with command `gunicorn service:app --log-file=-`
2014-08-26 11:04:44 [2] [INFO] 1 workers
at=info method=GET path="/" host=my-app.herokuapp.com request_id=e152c661-b633-4870-aeba-68cea3cc8039 fwd="73.24.16.159" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=13ms status=200 bytes=407
Slug compilation finished
State changed from up to starting
Release v10 created by my@email.com
Deploy be32f3c by my@email.com
2014-08-26 11:04:29 [2] [INFO] 1 workers
Slug compilation started
2014-08-26 11:04:14 [2] [INFO] 1 workers
2014-08-26 11:03:59 [2] [INFO] 1 workers
```

Comment: I'm not sure what's causing the problem, but the log entries for requests are lacking the leading timestamp which is likely why loggly can't read them.

Comment: @LukasEklund These are the standard Heroku logs and Loggly natively supports Heroku as an input source, so I don't think the lack of a timestamp is the problem. In addition Loggly add their own timestamp to logs, they do not rely on the logs having a timestamp AFAIK

Comment: Interesting, I've never seen heroku logs w/o a timestamp before. For that matter, I've never seen any server logs w/o a timestamp before.

Comment: @LukasEklund Using `heroku logs -t` some logs have 2 timestamps and some have a single timestamp + I copied the logs in the question from loggly. So maybe loggly removed the first timestamp and set it apart, as they do have a separate column with a timestamp which I thought they generated, but perhaps they just extracted the timestamp which appears on all heroku log lines. So now I wonder why some heroku logs have two timestamps...

Answer (score 2):

Although initially I thought this was a problem on our side, Loggly's support admitted there's a problem with their parsing of Heroku logs and that they are working on it.

I'm keeping this question open until Loggly fix this problem in case others will search for it. Once Loggly fix it, I'll delete the question.